# Is model building without variable selection a sensible idea?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, modeling, multiple-comparisons

I am interested in understanding the relationship between a group of four variables - one is a response variable , `Y`, and other variables (`A`, `B` and `C`) are being considered as predictors. It has been previously shown that changing `A` changes `Y`, but nothing has been said about the relationship between `B` and `Y` or the relationship between `C` and `Y`. To test whether any of these untested relationships actually exist, I was going to use a full model, `Y ~ A + B + C`.

However, I am also considering an incremental, model building method where I have the following four models:

1. `Y ~ A`
2. `Y ~ A + B`
3. `Y ~ A + C`
4. `Y ~ A + B + C`

I will check whether model assumptions are being satisfied by all these models, and report all the estimates and confidence intervals as well.

The idea behind this model building method lies in developing a narrative that conveys information about simpler models first and then about complex models, describing any significant relationship between `Y` and `B` or between `Y` and `C` while at the same time confirming if previously reported relationship between `Y` and `A` exists in my data.

The articles about hypothesis testing or estimation I have read often asks to consider and report a full model instead of using any variable selection method. In light of such readings, I have felt uncomfortable about the model building method described above. Could you share your opinions about whether such model building method makes sense or not?

Comment: How are A, B, and C related to each other? What do you think is the direction of the relationships between A, B, and C. In other words, are these confounding or intervening variables, or maybe colliders.

Comment: A is a binary variable related to manipulation in a psychology experiment - condition 1 vs. condition 2 - while B and C were measured before the experiment was carried out. Thus, it would not make sense to talk about the effect of A on B or on C. B and C, however, can have opposite effect on the perception of A, but B and C have also been shown to be independent of each other.